# How to get word that is after indexOf("@") and add it to array

Tags: javascript

Im doing a javascript bot, that reads the chat whenever someone uses !example @example123
it would add user to an array using the word what's after the "@", since im new to Javascript, i have failed approx. 60 times already, and thought maybe someone here can help me out.

Here's a small example what's in my mind.
ps. The page has an API (API.sendChat("text")).

```
API.on(API.CHAT, onChat);
function example();    
 var msg = data.message;
 var args = msg.trim().split(" ");
 var array = new Array();
 var username = data.from
 array = [];
```

Tried:
     if (args[0] == "!example" && args[1].indexOf("@") //what's next?) {
     }

```
if (args[0] == "!example" && args[1] == username()) {
add user to array
}
```

Comment: Please include in your post some of the attempts you have made (even if the code doesn't work) - this is the best way to explain what you're trying to do. Don't forget to include the expected results.

Comment: Do you know about regular expressions?
Should help you for this problem I think (even if its not the only solution)

Comment: Sorry, i was adding the code, when it suddenly posted it.

Comment: Your code isn't showing us what you have tried to solve your problem.
Please post some of your 60 times failed, it could be helpful.

Comment: I've tried something like that, but i get it, that's wrong.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and feel free to ask if you have problem.

Comment: The problem is to get the word after ("@") character. Then use it where-ever i want. Example: !punch @bully > It comes out:
API.sendChat( data.from + " has punched the user:" + "@bully");

Comment: @MisterJ http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score -1):

as [the manual states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) `indexOf` takes a second parameter, instructing the function to search starting from specific position. So when you want to extract the word after the `@` sign you are lookign for the portion of text between `@` and the next space  eg

```
hello @valerj how are you
      ^      ^
      p1     p2
```

so you would use

```
p1   = str.indexOf('@');
p2   = str.indexOf(' ',p1);
name = str.substr(p1,p2-p1); //substr want start and length
```

yet as you see it would fail on a lot of strings like

```
hello @valerij, how are you
ping @valerij
             ^line end
```

you could adress this issue by using regex to obtain the `p2` eg

```
p2   = str.indexOf(/ ,.?!$/,p1);
```

but it might still fail. The best solution would be to use regex for all the operation eg

```
var myregexp = /@(\w+)\b/;
```

(the `\b` is `word boundary` and will take care of all punctuation, line endings and other characters)
and use this code

```
var userNames = [];
var match = myregexp.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
    //username is in match[1] (first capturing group)
    userNames.push(match[1]);
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

to populate the array with usernames mentioned in the chat message

Comment: I only need the array to be filled temporarily. So it would grab the name from the array when !example is used.

Comment: @Randy so whats the problem?